# How to get Visual Studio 2017 Performance Profiler to take into account non-managed code?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, performance, visual-studio-2017, profiling

When using the Visual Studio 2017 (Professional) Performance Profiler, (on .NET code) the only option for measuring CPU usage is "Sampling". But the sampling method doesn't take into account when managed code calls into non-managed code - like when running a DB query. So, the measured execution time of a function that calls into non-managed code is a lot less than it really should be.

I've heard of something called "Tier Interaction Profiler" (TIP), which, I think, would fix this problem, but it doesn't look like that exists in VS2017.

How can I fix this problem and profile my code correctly?

Comment: Can we assume this is this .net? Is this a web application?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/collecting-tier-interaction-data?view=vs-2019 could this help answer your question?

Comment: istepaniuk - Yes, it's .NET code. No, it's not a web app. Just a regular program that makes DB calls.

Comment: Are you sure your scenario is "call into non-managed code" and not "waiting for network traffic"?  There's a big difference, to a profiler, between a thread which is running code, any code, and a thread which is sleeping until I/O happens.  Even communication with a database server running as a separate process in your machine will cause your thread to *sleep* until the database engine transmits the results.

Comment: To use an analogy, a program making a database query is not working hard, it is sitting by the phone listening to hold music.  And the profiler knows the difference.

Comment: Ben - Yeah, but. 
#1 I want to know the "inclusive" (as opposed to just exclusive) execution time/percent of various functions. VS2017 does not do this correctly. If I make a DB call, then that should be included in the measured inclusive time/percent.
#2 VS2015 showed the correct value for this measurement (the inclusive value) including time spent in non-managed code.

Comment: Maybe I need VS2017 Enterprise instead of Professional to do the TIP thing?

Comment: Ben - I missed your 1st comment. A couple things. Even if a thread were waiting/sleeping/blocked, the sampler should still catch it. But there would probably be a problem if you were using async methods... maybe that's what you meant. My guess is that the problem is that the "missing execution time" corresponds with the time spent in non-managed code, but that's just my guess. I don't know what else it could be. Again VS2015 worked fine.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I don't need TIP. That's only if you want to look at DB queries.

Comment: It looks like doing instrumentation instead of sampling gives me the right results. But I'm running into a different problem. For some reason, I can't see the results of some of my instrumented dlls. I get some message about symbols not found, and in the Function Details window it dead ends with "Bottom of call stack" - when I should be seeing the functions in another dll (which I included in my list of instrumented dlls)

Comment: @K.Madden - Well, like I said in my last comment, I don't think TIP is the solution to my problem. And also, it looks like you'd need VS Enterprise (not Professional) to do that TIP thing.